# Wordpress woocommerce update product stock and status via php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, pdo

I would like to update the product stock quantity and current product status using php.

I have used this code which updates the required values perfectly.

//post_id query

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = :sku");
$stm->bindParam(":sku", $sku, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->execute();
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

//update stock by post_id query

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = :stock WHERE `post_id` LIKE :id AND `meta_key` LIKE '_stock'");
$stm->bindParam(":id", $row['post_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindParam(":stock", $stock, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();
```

//update stock by post_id query2

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` SET `stock_quantity` = :stock WHERE `sku` LIKE :sku");
$stm->bindParam(":sku", $sku, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stm->bindParam(":stock", $stock, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->execute();
```

//if stock 0 set to outofstock

```
if ($stock < 1){
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = 'outofstock' WHERE `post_id` LIKE :id AND `meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status'");
    $stm->bindParam(":id", $row['post_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` SET `stock_status` = 'outofstock' WHERE `sku` LIKE :sku");
    $stm->bindParam(":sku", $sku, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();
}
```

//if stock 1 or more set to instock

```
if ($stock > 0){
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = 'instock' WHERE `post_id` LIKE :id AND `meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status'");
    $stm->bindParam(":id", $row['post_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute();
    $stm = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` SET `stock_status` = 'instock' WHERE `sku` LIKE :sku");
    $stm->bindParam(":sku", $sku, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();
}
```

However, after finishing the script, the values are not updated on the product page.
If I open the product from the admin menu and check the product on the product page, now the values are refreshed, although I did not hit the save or update button in wordpress admin, just opened the product.

My question would be, is there any other parameters I need to set manually so that the product would update at the end user page? Did I miss out anything, or is there a function that needs to be run in order to initialize the new values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that flushing redis object cache updates the stock and current status, so my problem looks solved. On the top of my file I have added
`require_once('../wp-load.php');`
and at the end of the script added
`global $wp_object_cache;  $wp_object_cache->redis_instance()->flushall();`
to flush the cache.